# Split a line from a file into two strings

Tags: c

Struggling with this one a lot. I'm trying to read a file into an array of structs with each line being split into the two string attributes of the struct. Here what I have tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define KEYSIZE   8
#define DATASIZE 56

struct Record {
    char key[KEYSIZE];
    char data[DATASIZE];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Please enter a file name");
        return 0;
    }
    FILE *recordFile=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char ch;
    int lines =0;

    fseek(recordFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    lines = ftell(recordFile);
    fseek(recordFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lines=lines/64;

    struct Record recArr[lines]; 

    char  buffer[9];
    char buffer2[57];
    fgets(buffer, 9, recordFile);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        recArr[0].key[i]=buffer[i];
    }
    fgets(buffer2, 57, recordFile);
    for(int i=0;i<57;i++)
    {
        recArr[0].data[i]=buffer2[i];
    }

}
```

Note that I am just editing the first member of the array for testing purposes. My current implementation gets me the correct result for the data attribute but the key attribute becomes the entire line, which is what I cannot figure out. This only happens if I edit the data attribute. If I remove the section editing the data attribute, the key attribute correctly displays the first 8 characters of the line.

Comment: Two strings walk into a bar. The first says, "Can I have a beer, please?You'll have to excuse my friend he's not null terminated.". The second says, "You'll have to excuse my friend, he's not null terminated." (Hint, hint).

Comment: How do I fix this exactly? I tried directly adding \0 to each char array but the problem remained.

Comment: Show the content of the file.

Comment: So, if the input buffers are +1 with respect to the size of the data (presumably to account for a null terminator), then why aren't the buffers in your record structure??

Comment: Here is an example of a couple lines 


e06de319. Record Number: 00000000.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz x


08517fde. Record Number: 00000001.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz x

Comment: Also, why are you dropping 1 in the limit of your first 'for' loop? (`I < 8`, not 9)

Comment: Use a single buffer long enough to contain each full line; read each line into it using `fgets()`. Then, use `sscanf()` to scan the contents of the line into the fields of the first unused entry in your array. The value it returns is the number of fields converted successfully. Consider trying something vaguely similar to `if (sscanf(linebuffer, "%7s %55[^\n]", array[k].key, array[k].data) != 2) linebuffer_has_incorrectly_formatted_data(); else linebuffer_has_correctly_formatted_data();` where `k` is the number of lines already correctly scanned.